# Ternary Search Tree / N-Gram Model in Python

Tags: python, performance, tree, memory-optimization, natural-language-processing

I implemented a word n-gram model using a character ternary search tree. It is intended to be passed a generator that yields a long sequence of words (from a corpus) and its requirements are that it

- can return frequencies and probabilities for word n-grams
- allows providing a vocabulary, such that n-grams containing words not
  in the vocabulary are not counted
- allows providing a list of
  targets, so that only n-grams ending in a target are counted (as
  probabilities for these are needed)

I find that it works as expected, but it is quite slow and consumes a lot of memory. For n-grams of length 4, trained on a corpus of about 1 billion words, right now it consumes >120GB of memory, despite providing a vocabulary that consists of words with a minimum frequency of 5, and it has been running for nearly 30 already. I know that Python requires a lot of memory, but I'm wondering if I'm missing something that would make it faster and maybe less memory intensive.

File tst.py:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, char):
        self.char = char
        self.count = 0

        self.lo = None
        self.eq = None
        self.hi = None


class TernarySearchTree():
    """Ternary search tree that stores counts for n-grams
    and their subsequences.
    """

    def __init__(self, splitchar=None):
        """Initializes TST.

        Parameters
        ----------
        splitchar : str
            Character that separates tokens in n-gram.
            Counts are stored for complete n-grams and
            each sub-sequence ending in this character
        """
        self._root = None
        self._splitchar = splitchar
        self._total = 0

    def insert(self, string):
        """Insert string into Tree.

        Parameters
        ----------
        string : str
            String to be inserted.
        """
        self._root = self._insert(string, self._root)
        self._total += 1

    def frequency(self, string):
        """Return frequency of string.

        Parameters
        ----------
        string : str


        Returns
        -------
        int
            Frequency
        """
        if not string:
            return self._total

        node = self._search(string, self._root)

        if not node:
            return 0

        return node.count

    def _insert(self, string, node):
        """Insert string at a given node.
        """
        if not string:
            return node

        char, *rest = string

        if node is None:
            node = Node(char)

        if char == node.char:
            if not rest:
                node.count += 1
                return node
            else:
                if rest[0] == self.splitchar:
                    node.count += 1
                node.eq = self._insert(rest, node.eq)

        elif char < node.char:
            node.lo = self._insert(string, node.lo)

        else:
            node.hi = self._insert(string, node.hi)

        return node

    def _search(self, string, node):
        """Return node that string ends in.
        """
        if not string or not node:
            return node

        char, *rest = string

        if char == node.char:
            if not rest:
                return node
            return self._search(rest, node.eq)

        elif char < node.char:
            return self._search(string, node.lo)

        else:
            return self._search(string, node.hi)

    def __contains__(self, string):
        """Adds "string in TST" syntactic sugar.
        """
        node = self._search(string, self._root)
        if node:
            return node.count

        return False

    @property
    def splitchar(self):
        return self._splitchar
```

File language_model.py:

```
from collections import deque
from tst import TernarySearchTree

class ContainsEverything:
"""Dummy container that mimics containing everything.
Has .add() method to mimic set.
"""

    def __contains__(self, _):
        return True

    def add(self, _):
        pass


class LanguageModel():
    """N-gram (Markov) model that uses a ternary search tree.
    Tracks frequencies and calculates probabilities.

    Attributes
    ----------
    n : int
        Size of n-grams to be tracked.
    vocabulary : set
        If provided, n-grams containing words not in vocabulary are skipped.
        Can be other container than set, if it has add method.
    targets : container
        If provided, n-grams not ending in target are counted as
        ending in "OOV" (OutOfVocabulary) instead, so probabilities
        can still be calculated.
    boundary : str
        N-grams crossing boundary will not be counted,
        e.g. sentence </s> or document </doc> meta tags
    splitchar : str
        String that separates tokens in n-grams
    """

    def __init__(self, n, boundary="</s>", splitchar="#",
                 vocabulary=None, targets=None):
        """
        Parameters
        ----------
        n : int
            Size of n-grams to be tracked.
        boundary : str
            N-grams crossing boundary will not be counted,
            e.g. sentence </s> or document </doc> meta tags
        splitchar : str
            String that separates tokens in n-grams
        vocabulary : set
            If provided, n-grams with words not in vocabulary are skipped.
            Can be other container than set, if it has add method.
        targets : container
            If provided, n-grams not ending in target are counted as
            ending in "OOV" (OutOfVocabulary) instead, so probabilities
            can still be calculated.
        """
        if not targets:
            targets = ContainsEverything()

        if not vocabulary:
            vocabulary = ContainsEverything()

        self._n = n
        self._counts = TernarySearchTree(splitchar)
        self._vocabulary = vocabulary
        self._targets = targets
        self._boundary = boundary
        self._splitchar = splitchar

    def train(self, sequence):
        """Train model on all n-grams in sequence.

        Parameters
        ----------
        sequence : iterable of str
            Sequence of tokens to train on.

        Notes
        -----
        A sequence [A, B, C, D, E] with n==3 will result in these
        n-grams:
          [A, B, C]
          [B, C, D]
          [C, D, E]
          [D, E]
          [E]
        """
        n_gram = deque(maxlen=self.n)
        for element in sequence:
            if element == self.boundary:
                # train on smaller n-grams at end of sentence
                # but exclude full n_gram if it was already trained
                # on in last iteration
                not_trained = len(n_gram) < self.n
                for length in range(1, len(n_gram) + not_trained):
                    self._train(list(n_gram)[-length:])
                n_gram.clear()
                continue

            n_gram.append(element)

            if len(n_gram) == self.n:
                if element not in self.targets:
                    self._train(list(n_gram)[:-1])
                    continue

                self._train(n_gram)

        # train on last n-grams in sequence
        # ignore full n-gram if it has already been trained on
        if len(n_gram) == self.n:
            n_gram = list(n_gram)[1:]
        for length in range(1, len(n_gram) + 1):
            self._train(list(n_gram)[-length:])

    def probability(self, sequence):
        """Returns probability of the sequence.

        Parameters
        ----------
        sequence : iterable of str
            Sequence of tokens to get the probability for

        Returns
        -------
        float or list of float
            Probability of last element or probabilities of all elements
        """
        try:
            n_gram = sequence[-self.n:]

        # if sequence is generator (cannot slice - TypeError),
        # run through it and return probability for final element
        except TypeError:
            n_gram = deque(maxlen=self.n)
            for element in sequence:
                n_gram.append(element)

        probability = self._probability(n_gram)
        return probability

    def frequency(self, n_gram):
        """Return frequency of n_gram.

        Parameters
        ----------
        n_gram : list/tuple of str

        Returns
        -------
        int
            Frequency
        """
        n_gram_string = self.splitchar.join(n_gram)
        frequency = self._counts.frequency(n_gram_string)
        return frequency

    def _train(self, n_gram):
        # test for OOV words
        for idx, word in enumerate(n_gram):
            if word not in self.vocabulary:
                n_gram = list(n_gram)[:idx]

        n_gram_string = self.splitchar.join(n_gram)
        self._counts.insert(n_gram_string)

    def _probability(self, n_gram):
        frequency = self.frequency(n_gram)

        if frequency == 0:
            return 0

        *preceding, target = n_gram
        total = self.frequency(preceding)

        probability = frequency / total
        return probability

    def __contains__(self, n_gram):
        return n_gram in self._counts

    @property
    def n(self):
        return self._n

    @property
    def vocabulary(self):
        return self._vocabulary

    @property
    def targets(self):
        return self._targets

    @property
    def boundary(self):
        return self._boundary

    @property
    def splitchar(self):
        return self._splitchar
```

For testing with random strings:

```
import random
from string import ascii_letters
from language_model import LanguageModel


def generate_random_strings(num):
    random.seed(69)
    for i in range(num):
        length = random.choice(range(12))
        yield "".join(random.choices(ascii_letters, k=length))


lm = LanguageModel(4)
lm.train(generate_random_strings(1000000))
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> class ContainsEverything:
> """Dummy container that mimics containing everything.
> Has .add() method to mimic set.
> """
> ```

The indentation is borked here, and needs correcting before the code will run.

---

I profiled with `guppy3` (inlining everything into one file for my convenience - that explains the `__main__` below):

```
lm = LanguageModel(4)
lm.train(generate_random_strings(10000))

from guppy import hpy
h = hpy(lm)
print(h.heap())
```

Nearly all of the memory was accounted for in the top two lines:

```
Partition of a set of 502128 objects. Total size = 43108362 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0 233701  47 26174512  61  26174512  61 dict of __main__.Node
     1 233701  47 13087256  30  39261768  91 __main__.Node
```

I'm not entirely sure where the `dict of __main__.Node` comes from, but clearly `Node` is the culprit, and each node is contributing 56 bytes inherently and a further 112 bytes indirectly.

However, looking at the use of the tree:

> ```
>         self._counts = TernarySearchTree(splitchar)
>         ...
>         frequency = self._counts.frequency(n_gram_string)
>         ...
>         self._counts.insert(n_gram_string)
>         ...
>         return n_gram in self._counts
> ```

I can't see any reason to use a tree. There's no use of internal nodes. As far as I can see, it can easily be replaced by a `Counter`, whereupon the memory usage drops by 90%:

```
Partition of a set of 34724 objects. Total size = 4141426 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0   9838  28   884914  21    884914  21 str
     1   8509  25   613768  15   1498682  36 tuple
     2    415   1   365544   9   1864226  45 type
     3   2226   6   320544   8   2184770  53 types.CodeType
     4   4329  12   309952   7   2494722  60 bytes
     5      1   0   295024   7   2789746  67 collections.Counter
```